# I'm performing a SCD-Type 2 logic in BigQuery and I need to figure out how to update the end date of an old record that's been updated comparing MD5s

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, md5, scd2

Below is an example of my query I have so far. I'm using MD5 hash functions to compare the two tables for updates. I want to be able to update the end_date column in my old record to the current_timestamp when there's an update. And the updated record to to have an end_date of '9999-12-31 23:59:59'

```
INSERT INTO target_table
SELECT 
a.user_id,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS start_date,
CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59' AS TIMESTAMP) AS end_date,
a.first_name
a.md5_cd

FROM
(SELECT * FROM source_table)a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM target_table)b

ON a.md5_cd = b.md5_cd
AND a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.md5_cd IS NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what needs to be added? I'm trying to avoid using a merge statement. The target_table updates the table with a new record when the md5_cd doesn't match but it doesn't change the end_date to the current timestamp.

This is the result I want if I changed the value of Dan to Pat.
[image]

but I'm getting this.
[image]

Here's my source table query:

```
INSERT INTO source_table
SELECT
A.user_id,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as start_date
CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59' AS TIMESTAMP) AS end_date,
A.first_name,
to_hex(md5(A.first_name)) as md5_cd

FROM
(
 SELECT
     '1' AS user_id,
     'Dan' as first_name

 )A;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample and expected data?

Comment: Yes! I just provided some

Comment: You need a LEAD windows function here. Something like this COALESCE(LEAD(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_date) - 1, CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59' AS TIMESTAMP) AS EndDate

Comment: Where would this be placed in my query?

Comment: Can you share your data for `source_table` and `target_table` as well? Just so the community can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: Does your `source_table` only have 1 row? If not, can you provide somewhat a complete data? Does `target_table` contain any data? If so, can you include sample data for `target_table` as well? How did you come up with the expected data? Did you `select * from target_table`? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)